# Is a comma necessary in this context?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, commas, subordinate-clauses

Grammarly is indicating I need to add a comma before **often**. However, I think it is not necessary since the phrase "*often the data required is not available*" is creating a subordinate clause with the text before.

> Because in places like my region *often the data required is not available,* I want to learn the procedure to collect it in a real-life situation, which I can do in the fieldwork conducted this semester.

Comment: I think your phrasing sounds "awkward". Relocate adverbial ***often*** so it's nearer the relevant verb: *Because in places like my region the data required **is often** not available*. OR (with a slight change of emphasis) put it after the negation *(...is **not often** available).* Another minor style choice: I'd refer to ***the required data*** rather than ***the data required*** (but that's just my preference).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why not just show it? Or put in an answer. Your comment are so hard to decipher for a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that punctuation is not grammar; it does not exist in the spoken language. It is a set of conventions that are not universal.

As FumbleFingers implied in a comment, the sentence is quite awkward, and punctuation would help. I have not found Grammerly to be ideal, and you have not given its complete review of the sentence. But here is how I would punctuate your word order

> Because, in places like my region, often the data required is not available, I ...

I’d punctuate it with that **pair** of commas because that unusually placed prepositional phrase of “in places ...” would be framed by pauses in spoken English to indicate a somewhat unusual word order. With a more normal word order, I’d punctuate it as

> Because often the data required is not available in places like my region, I ...

I do not mind the unusual word order with “often” as a technique of emphasis, but then I agree with FF not to invert “required” and “data” because too many disruptions of the most common word order make a sentence hard to follow. So here is how I might revise your sentence

> Because so often the required data are not available in my region, I ...

I would not object to this alternate punctuation

> Because, so often, the required data are not available in my region, I ...